# Best way to chain Observables using RxJs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rxjs, observable

In this scenario, what would be the best was to chain the Observables and to dispatch the `SEARCH_QUERY_COMPLETE` action once all the subscriptions are completed? I noticed that `forkJoin` is deprecated...

```
const launchSearchQuery = () => {
    mainDispatch({
      type: ActionTypes.LAUNCH_SEARCH_QUERY,
    });

    if (mainState.searchSection.searchQuery !== "") {
      // get order details
      orderDetailRepository.getOrderDetails(mainState.searchSection.searchQuery).subscribe((response) => {
        searchResultCards.push(mapSearchResultCard(response, DashboardSectionTitles.ORDER_DETAILS));
      });
      // get customer details
      customerDetailRepository.getCustomerDetails(mainState.searchSection.searchQuery).subscribe((response) => {
        searchResultCards.push(mapSearchResultCard(response, DashboardSectionTitles.CUSTOMER_DETAILS));
      });
      // get equipment details
      equipmentDetailRepository.getEquipmentDetails(mainState.searchSection.searchQuery).subscribe((response) => {
        searchResultCards.push(mapSearchResultCard(response, DashboardSectionTitles.EQUIPMENT_DETAILS));
      });
      // get equipment return details
      equipmentReturnDetailRepository
        .getEquipmentReturnDetails(mainState.searchSection.searchQuery)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          searchResultCards.push(mapSearchResultCard(response, DashboardSectionTitles.EQUIPMENT_RETURN_DETAILS));
        });
    }
    
    // !!! only execute this when all subscriptions are completed !!!
    mainDispatch({
        type: ActionTypes.SEARCH_QUERY_COMPLETE,
        payload: searchResultCards,
    });

  };
```

Here is the blueprint of `getOrderDetails`

```
export interface IOrderDetailRepository {
  getOrderDetails: (query: string) => Observable<IOrderDetail[]>;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that `forkJoin` is deprecated? (it seems to be just fine)

Comment: As of version 6.6.0 I get this message: `@deprecated — Use the version that takes an array of Observables instead`

Comment: It's just previous signature, you can still use it by passing array or object with observables. See examples on [forkJoin documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` like this -

```
const launchSearchQuery = () => {
            mainDispatch({
              type: ActionTypes.LAUNCH_SEARCH_QUERY,
            });
        

            
            if (mainState.searchSection.searchQuery !== "") {
                forkJoin([
                    // get order details
                    orderDetailRepository.getOrderDetails(mainState.searchSection.searchQuery),
                    // get customer details
                    customerDetailRepository.getCustomerDetails(mainState.searchSection.searchQuery),
                    // get equipment details
                    equipmentDetailRepository.getEquipmentDetails(mainState.searchSection.searchQuery),
                    // get equipment return details
                    equipmentReturnDetailRepository.getEquipmentReturnDetails(mainState.searchSection.searchQuery)
                ]).subscribe(([orderDetails, customerDetails, equipMentDetails, equimentReturnDetails]) => {
                    searchResultCards.push(mapSearchResultCard(orderDetails, DashboardSectionTitles.ORDER_DETAILS));
                    searchResultCards.push(mapSearchResultCard(customerDetails, DashboardSectionTitles.CUSTOMER_DETAILS));
                    searchResultCards.push(mapSearchResultCard(equipMentDetails, DashboardSectionTitles.EQUIPMENT_DETAILS));
                    searchResultCards.push(mapSearchResultCard(equimentReturnDetails, DashboardSectionTitles.EQUIPMENT_RETURN_DETAILS));
    
                    // !!! only execute this when all subscriptions are completed !!!
                    mainDispatch({
                        type: ActionTypes.SEARCH_QUERY_COMPLETE,
                        payload: searchResultCards,
                    });
                });
            }
        
          };
```

Comment: got it, you can still use the `forkJoin([])` override that takes an array as a parameter.

Comment: yes, `forJoin`. Actually, `forkJoin` earlier syntax was deprecated (which used to take observables as different params). As per new syntax, it takes array of observables.